# mysql query to find data less then today date

Tags: mysql

```
my date is stored in database 11/01/2015 12:00 AM - 11/01/2015 11:59 PM As Event_duration and i the first date is event starting date and after '-' is event ending date and i want to echo count of active event so i want to compare end date  11/01/2015 11:59 PM from today date time in my sql query to print in active event count please help me with this what should be the query to find active event count after exploding the date in database after dash '-' please give me the proper solution for this
i m trying this code
```

and it is producing this output:
    11/02/2015 13:13 PM < 11/03/2015 11:59 PM
    11/02/2015 13:13 PM < 11/03/2015 11:59 PM
    11/02/2015 13:13 PM < 11/27/2015 11:59 PM
    11/02/2015 13:13 PM < 11/01/2015 11:59 PM
    11/02/2015 13:13 PM < 12/01/2015 12:00 AM 
    but Im not able to compare date :( Please give me solution

```
     <?php
                         echo $Qry_Act_Count="SELECT SPLIT_STR(Event_Duration, '-', 2) as Active_Event_Time_Show from create_event";
                            $Act_Event_Count=0;
                            $Act_Count3=mysqli_query($con,$Qry_Act_Count);

                           date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
                           $Act_date = date("m/d/Y H:i A");

                           while ($Act_Rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Act_Count3))
                            {
                                  echo '<br>' . $Act_date  . '>' . $Act_Rows['Active_Event_Time_Show'];
                                  if($Act_date <= $Act_Rows['Active_Event_Time_Show']){

                                         echo $Act_Event_Count++;
                                        }
                                          }
                                                ?>
```

Comment: I think it makes sense to convert your `event_duration` [VARCHAR] to `event_start` [DATETIME | TIMESTAMP] and `event_end` [DATETIME | TIMESTAMP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use **[SUBSTRING_INDEX( )](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)** to get the appropriate date and then cast it to a valid date with **[STR_TO_DATE( )](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)** like so

```
SELECT whatever
FROM table
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_date, '-', -1)),'%m/%d/%Y %r') < NOW()
```

to break it down

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_date, '-', -1)` says give me the last element that can be split by the delimiter '-'

`TRIM()` just removes any additional whitespace since you have

`STR_TO_DATE()` converts that string to a date of a particular format. in your case you want it month/day/year

the `%r` is to account for the 11:59 PM from the docs

> %r - Time in 12 hour AM or PM format (hh:mm:ss AM/PM)

if you wanted you could replace `%r` with `%h:%i %p` but I prefer `%r` since its cleaner and less code to write :)

Answer (score 0):

You need some steps for this process :-

First use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('11/01/2015 12:00 AM-11/01/2015 11:59 PM','-',-1)
```

second use `Str_to_date`

```
Str_to_date(
SUBSTRING_INDEX('11/01/2015 12:00 AM-11/01/2015 11:59 PM','-',1),'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i')
```

Try this query:-

```
SELECT * FROM table
 WHERE Str_to_date(
SUBSTRING_INDEX('11/01/2015 12:00 AM-11/01/2015 11:59 PM','-',1),'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i') 
< NOW()
```

or use `interval 12 HOUR` for get `24 hours format`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
str_to_date(SUBSTRING_INDEX('11/01/2015 12:00 AM-11/01/2015 1:59 PM','-',-1),'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i')
+ interval 12 HOUR < NOW()
```